# cannot remove badly installed packages

Tags: dpkg

Cannot install anything, cannot remove anything. Please help.

This is not a duplicate. First of all that is a completely different problem. Second, I tried the solution (command line one) and obviously nothing changed. Here is the new results of apt-get update:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:3 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                           
Ign:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease      
Ign:6 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 InRelease      
Get:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release [3,457 B]
Ign:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease     
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Get:10 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release [3,457 B]
Hit:11 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Hit:12 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Hit:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease             
Hit:14 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                        
Hit:15 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview InRelease                       
Get:16 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release.gpg [801 B]
Hit:17 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease            
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:19 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease          
Ign:16 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release.gpg  
Hit:20 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release       
Get:21 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release.gpg [801 B]
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Ign:21 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release.gpg
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:27 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu bionic-getdeb InRelease                
  Connection failed [IP: 144.76.200.19 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 68818C72E52529D4
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BC711F9BA15703C6
E: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

System specs:
Asus A456U
Intel i5 6200U
8GB Ram 
Nvidia GT930M / Intel HD 4400
Ubuntu 18.04.1
Originally windows, but removed windows and installed ubuntu fully from usb.

What I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

outputs:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:2 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:7 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease     
Hit:10 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                          
Get:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release [3,457 B]
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Get:14 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release.gpg [801 B]
Ign:14 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release.gpg  
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Hit:16 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                        
Hit:17 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview InRelease                       
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease  
Ign:21 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease     
Ign:22 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 InRelease     
Get:23 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release [3,457 B]
Hit:24 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release       
Get:26 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release.gpg [801 B]
Ign:26 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release.gpg   
Err:27 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu bionic-getdeb InRelease                
  Connection failed [IP: 144.76.200.19 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 68818C72E52529D4
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BC711F9BA15703C6
E: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-efi-amd64.config: 35: /etc/default/grub: nouveau.blacklist=1: not found
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package grub-pc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic (4.15.0-32.35) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic (4.15.0-30.32) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic (4.15.0-32.35) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: nouveau.blacklist=1: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic (4.15.0-30.32) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-30-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: nouveau.blacklist=1: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
 linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Have tried the following as well:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Outputs:

```
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-efi-amd64.config: 35: /etc/default/grub: nouveau.blacklist=1: not found
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package grub-pc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic (4.15.0-32.35) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic (4.15.0-30.32) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic (4.15.0-32.35) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: nouveau.blacklist=1: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic (4.15.0-30.32) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-30-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: nouveau.blacklist=1: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
 linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic
```

Comment: How does a ppa repository work and how is it that this ends up being a 404? Why aren't the urls updated as time goes by? Shouldn't there be a test suite before each ubuntu update that checks that each repository returns a 200 status code?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: Did that, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found on this line:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: nouveau.blacklist=1: not found
```

This was a line I added a while ago to force ubuntu to use the nvidia drivers vs the nouveau drivers. Apparently the instructions I followed were unclear/wrong and the command wasn't parsed as a valid instruction. Thus, the autoremove script failed. Removing this line, then running autoremove, apt-get update and apt-get install -f, clean, autoclean, etc fixed the problem.

I also uninstalled mongodb because screw that, if the repos aren't updated I'm not interested in installing that software. Removed mongo repos, some ubuntu theme repos, and sure enough apt-get update worked fine (Except for one line related to ubuntu bionic release, though I'm not usre how to remove that. not causing problems though).